# Bad SIP URI in To header field

Tags: asterisk, sip

We are creating Asterisk<->Lync trunk.

The Asterisk is under providers control. I am in charge of Lync. I'm slightly familiar with Asterisk.

We created a trunk. Everything was fine until provider restarted their Asterisk server. Now the Asterisk sends strange SIP INVITES with `sip:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5068` (where `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is the IP address of the Lync Server) in To header field. Before the restart it was something like `sip:username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`.

Provider doesn't know what to do. We are close to deadline with the project.

What do you think should we do to make to SIP URI be like that `sip:username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`?

P.S.: user recreation didn't help. Changing extension didn't help too.

Answer (score 0):

On asterisk site need:

- Check `sip.conf`, find line like:

  ```
  bind=0.0.0.0:5068
  ```
- Change to:

  ```
  bind=0.0.0.0:5060
  ```

Also check nat settings (externip/externdomain)

Also you can try change on lynx `port=5068`, but i can't say where it is.

Comment: Lync port is already 5068. Everything was working until Asterisk was restarted.

Comment: Sorry, this site is Q&A, not troubleshooting resource. I give you posible answers.